# Php headers not working, headers not sent

Tags: php, html, redirect

I'm coding a template engine, herefor i've made a function:

```
public function getFilename() {
    $config = new Config('template_config.ini');
    if($this->filepath == null){
        $this->filename = $config->get("file")["default"];
    }else{
        if(array_key_exists($this->filepath, $config->get("file"))){
            $this->filename = $config->get("file")[$this->filepath];
        } else {
            Redirect::to("/404");
            return $this;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

The code ran fine, until it didn't anymore. It runs to the right box and it runs the redirect function that is equal to: `header("Location: ".$input); exit;`. After the header it echo's out things fine, the header is just not linking through.

This all is called in a index:

```
use lib\Template\Template_loader;
use lib\Api\Input;
require_once("Nytrix/autoloader.php");
new Template_loader(Input::get("path"));
```

Then this calls the constructor, this calls the filename function:

```
public function __construct($filepath){
    $this->filepath = $filepath;
    $this->getFilename();

}
```

The `Redirect::to($argument);` function is: `header("Location: ".$argument);`. No laravel implemented

Comment: and your question is? you say, redirect is working so headers work (location) ... and then ask Why soes it not redirect?

Comment: Can you provide more code? Specifically code that shows how you are calling `getFilename`. Also this function doesn't make sense, why does getFilename redirect? After sending a redirect header, you should `exit;`.

Comment: My question is why it does not redirect. As i don't get errors and i just want to redirect, let that be my problem ;). The `exit;` does not help a thing.

Comment: @Nytrix And you need to provide more code. Are you sure that `Redirect::to` is being run? And are you sure that `Redirect::to` is actually sending the correct headers? Place an echo right before your `Redirect::to` to see that it's flowing correctly into that if-block.

Comment: I've all checked that, it flows to the right box and it runs the Redirect:to() function perfectly. Errors are on, there are no errors. I works fine up to the part of the redirect and it just does nothing with it. It runs the code behind the header too. Just not the header, and they are not already sent

Comment: The location header should be set with an absolute URL instead of a relative one. If that doesn't work verify that you're receiving the header from the server by using your network tab or a HTTP sniffer such as Fiddler4.

Comment: The absolute url worked, i tried relative again and it worked? Confusion level > 9000

Comment: May be `return Redirect::to('/');` ?

Answer (score 1):

This code is a little off. Calling `Redirect::to("/404");` doesn't set the headers or anything. It generates an `Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse` object that needs to be returned from the controller.

Comment: Now i get this answer, i've made the Redirect::to() function myself. No laravel implemented, the laravel tag is not right. Someone added that, it is all php.

Comment: @Nytrix Ahh, that makes a lot more sense. I was a bit confused as I didn't see anything really Laravel specific, except the `Redirect::to()` functionality. Thanks for clarifying!